# How to run a regression with dates and variables (each variable linked to a stock)?

Tags: r, date, variables, vector, regression

I am trying to run a regression with dates (lines) and variables (columns).
My problem: We haeve 60 stocks and for each of them 5 variables. 
It is the same variables for each stocks but I have more than 2800 dates. 
Do you have any idea to help me with it? How to obtain a single regression model, since for now I can only do 60 seperated regressions ?

Thank you,

Mathilde

Comment: Try something like `by(<mydata>, <mydata>$stock, function(s) lm(y ~ x, s))`.

Comment: Hi, thank you Jay for your answer. 
I tried this model with two stocks but both estimates are the same for the regression models. I also obtained 2 regressions while i would like to have a single regression. Do you know the interpretation of these results ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question, thanks.